# Adding values in a bidimensional array multiple 2 and 5

Tags: arrays, matrix

This is an example: how we can use bidimensional array and also using multiple of 2 and 5.

How we can improve this Array: the goal is with numbers from 1 to 100, save the multiple of 2 in the left side of the array and the multiple of 5 in the right side of the array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
int a = 100;
int b = 2;
double[][] mUnidad = new double[a][b];

for (int i = 0; i < mUnidad.length; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < mUnidad[i].length; j++) {
    if (i % 2 == 0 ) {
        mUnidad[i][0] = i;
    }
    if(i % 5 ==0){
        mUnidad[i][1] = i;
    }
}
}

for (int i = 0; i < mUnidad.length; i++) {
for (int j = 0; j < mUnidad[i].length; j++) {
    System.out.print(mUnidad[i][j] + "\t");
}
System.out.println("");
}
}
```

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do.

Comment: smell like a homework...

Answer (score 0):

I also do not understand what your homework is.. Also you are using Java code while requesting some C++, I took 2 minutes of my time to help you and that's the least I can do

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    const int a = 100;
    const int b = 2;
    double mUnidad[a][b] = { -1 };
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (i % 2 == 0) {
            mUnidad[i][0] = i;
        }
        if (i % 5 == 0){
            mUnidad[i][1] = i;
        }
    }

    cout << "multiple of 2 " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (mUnidad[i][0] != 0){
            cout << i << " is divisible by 2 " << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "multiple of 5 " << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        if (mUnidad[i][1] != 0){
            cout << i << " is divisible by 5 " << endl;
        }
    }
    system("pause");
    return 0;

}
```